# GUI to subset a data frame in R

Tags: r, user-interface, filter, subset, gwidgets

I am building a custom GUI in R for work, and I need to have a part that can select a subset of a dataframe based on variable values (i.e. select all females that are above 50 etc.). I am building the GUI with gwidgets, but I am stuck with regards to how this filter can be implemented. Specifically how to create a widget that allows the user to select one or more filters and then return the filtered data frame.

Here is a small sample from the data I am working with:

```
structure(list(kunde = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3), 
               bank = c(7,98, 3, 3, 98, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2)),
          .Names = c("kunde", "bank"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: ??? How do you plan to subset on "female" when there is no such value in your data-object?

Comment: The gender variable is in the data, but I just used it as an example in the question. I imagine any example that shows how to filter with the posted subset can be easily adopted to also filter a given gender variable ;)

Comment: You may wish to consider embedding your GUI within a larger framework such as Deducer or R Commander. You will get some of these data manipulation tasks for free. (e.g. http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Subset )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some examples of similar things in the `ProgGUIinR` package. Here is one of them:

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")
options(repos="http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN")
d <- available.packages()       # pick a cran site

w <- gwindow("test of filter")
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
ed <- gedit("", cont=g)
tbl <- gtable(d, cont=g, filter.FUN="manual", expand=TRUE)

ourMatch <- function(curVal, vals) {
  grepl(curVal, vals)
}

id <- addHandlerKeystroke(ed, handler=function(h, ...) {
  vals <- tbl[, 1, drop=TRUE]
  curVal <- svalue(h$obj)
  vis <- ourMatch(curVal, vals)
  visible(tbl) <- vis
})
```

For your purpose, you might want to use `gcheckboxgroup` or `gcombobox` to select factor levels or a level and filter by that. The key is the `visible<-` method of the `gtable` object is used to filter the displayed items.

If you are game, you can try the `gfilter` widget in `gWidgets2` which as of know is just on my github site (use `install_packages("gWidgets2", "jverzani")` from devtools, also `gWidgets2RGtk2`). This may be just what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

With your data object and testing one of the variables, this is a simplified version of `subset.data.frame`:

```
tmp <- 
structure(list(kunde = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3), bank = c(7, 
98, 3, 3, 98, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2)), .Names = c("kunde", "bank"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

 getsub <- function(obj, logexpr) if (missing(logexpr)) {return(obj)
        } else {e <- substitute(logexpr)
         r <- eval(e, obj, parent.frame())
         if (!is.logical(r)) 
             stop("'subset' must evaluate to logical")
         r <- r & !is.na(r)
         obj[r, ] }

 getsub(tmp, bank <50)
#--------------
   kunde bank
1      3    7
3      3    3
4      3    3
6      3    2
7      3    2
8      1    1
9      3    7
10     3    2
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but how would you implement this with gwidgets?